# github Action erorr: xcodebuild: error: '.xcproject' does not exist

Tags: github-actions, xcodebuild

Here is the workflow execution log:

```
Run xcodebuild clean build -project ExGithubAction/ExGithubAction.xcproject -scheme ExGithubAction
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild clean build -project ExGithubAction.xcproject -scheme ExGithubAction

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

xcodebuild: error: 'ExGithubAction.xcproject' does not exist.
Error: Process completed with exit code 66.
```

How can I get past the error `'ExGithubAction.xcproject' does not exist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as a step (after the `uses: actions/checkout@v3`) to do a `ls` and confirm that `ExGithubAction.xcproject` is indeed checked out.

Second, as in [this thread](https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard/issues/26), specify the full path:

```
xcodebuild \
    -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyProject \
    -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 \
    -configuration Release \
    clean build \
    OBJROOT=$(PWD)/build \
    SYMROOT=$(PWD)/build
```

(adapt it and remove the options you do not need)

If you have a `obfuscate_project` script, you have would need to provide proper values to variables corresponding to your project in the first section of the script and commit those changes.

```
# General build options
# WORKSPACE=YourWorkspace.xcworkspace
PROJECT=YourProject.xcodeproj
SCHEME=YourScheme
CONFIGURATION=Release
SDK=7.1
```